# How does variable allocation works in C++?

Tags: c++, c++20

I have this in the `main.cpp` body (how is it called? global?)

```
ofstream s;
...
int main ... {
    s = ofstream("somefile.txt");
...
```

then **another thread** uses it once a day to rollover:

```
s.close();
// do I need to cleanup in between?
s = ofstream("anotherone.txt");
```

do I need to cleanup before `creating` new stream?

Comment: Are you asking whether there's some general concept of "cleaning up variables" in C++, or are you asking specifically about the mechanics of the `ofstream` class?

Comment: any object - do I need to delete it somehow? wont it leak memory after `s = ofstream("anotherone.txt");`?

Comment: I guess it depends on how well the class is defined. But, in simple terms, compare to a basic type: `int* p = new int; *p = 3; /* .do stuff */ *p = 4; delete p;` Do we leak memory here? Do we have to delete `p` and re-create between the two assignments?

Comment: NB: this is not class. its just a cpp file with `main` in it and the `s` is declared outside `main`. also you use `new` - I know what to do with it. I dont know what to do with var which is declared simply as `T v` and then `v = T();` <- is this same as `v = new T()` ?? then I should use `delete &v`? not sure it will compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`close()` is a member function defined in the class `ofstream`. It's not a destructor; it's not special in any way which fundamentally matters to the rules of the C++ language. For that matter, `s = ofstream("anotherone.txt")` is actually just another way to spell the line of code `s.assignment_operator(ofstream("anotherone.txt"))`, except that instead of `assignment_operator` it's spelled `operator=`. (Note that in this case, the value which is passed to the member function is a temporary value, and is destroyed after the function returns. That doesn't necessarily imply anything specific about what happens with opening and closing files; it's just how the language works.)

A global variable exists throughout the entire life of the program; the precise semantics during startup and shutdown are a little tricky, but certainly during the "main phase" they always exist. The design of `ofstream` may put `s` into a different sort of state when `s.close()` is called, but that's entirely down to the design of `ofstream`, and is something that you'd discover by reading the documentation of that class rather than by reading the rules of the language.

Comment: thank you. but i am still unclear. i need simple yes or no - if i "assign" var like `s = class_a("somefile.txt");` and later `s = class_a("anotherone.txt");` - will there be a memory leak? or c++ compiler cleverly write some deallocation for `somefile` instance of the var before assigning `anotherone` ?

Comment: @BoppityBop **If the class in question is well-written,** your "yes/no" question is the same as asking "If I assign a variable like `int s = 2;` and later `s = 4;` will there be a memory leak?"

Comment: idk how do you compare a class to an integer but ok. yes that what I am asking.

Comment: @BoppityBop: How “you compare a class to an integer” is more or less the definition of well-written classes in C++.

Comment: @BoppityBop Again, it comes down to how the class in question is implemented. As it happens, `ofstream` is "well-behaved"; it relies on the ["move semantics"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics) introduced in C++11 to make assignment "just work". But the Standard Library in general was written by smart people, so it's not *that* easy to screw things up with almost any of its facilities.